# How to call root parent's function from n-th child window using javascript?

Tags: javascript

there.
Let's say that I don't know how many child window would be open by window.showModalDialog.
If it's only 1 depth between child and parent, it would be easy to call parent's function using javascript.
But I have to open a child window and from that child window to another child window, and another, and another.
I can't say how many depth.
Now, from the last child window, how can I call the root parent's function?
Anyone has any idea?

"Root Parent Window" -> child window -> child window -> child window ........n-th child window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose we are talking about recursion here.
If we know function name that must be called from root window then we may do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callRootFunction(wnd,funcName){
        if(wnd.opener)
            callRootFunction(wnd.opener,funcName);
        else
            wnd[funcName].call(this);
    }
</script>
```

this script must be in child windows and from any you can call

```
callRootFunction(window,'theRootFunction');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have changed wnd.opener -> wnd.dialogArguments as I open child windows by showModalDialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the topmost window 
you can just call this

window.top.abc();  //abc() is the function in the topmost window.